# Magento 2 override admin Controller Address Save.php

Tags: magento2.3, customer, adminhtml, customer-address, admin-controller

How to override admin controller address save.php

I am using this code -

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Address\Save"
                type="Companyname\Namespace\Controller\Adminhtml\Address\Save" />                

</config>
```

Save.php

```
<?php
namespace Companyname\Namespace\Controller\Adminhtml\Address;

class Save extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Address\Save
{
    

    public function execute()
    {
       echo "hello"; die;


        $customerId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('parent_id', false);
        $addressId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id', false);

        $error = false;
        try {
            /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer */
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);

            $addressForm = $this->formFactory->create(
                'customer_address',
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                [],
                false,
                false
            );
            $addressData = $addressForm->extractData($this->getRequest());
            $addressData = $addressForm->compactData($addressData);

            $addressData['region'] = [
                'region' => $addressData['region'] ?? null,
                'region_id' => $addressData['region_id'] ?? null,
            ];
            $addressToSave = $this->addressDataFactory->create();
            $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
                $addressToSave,
                $addressData,
                \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface::class
            );
            $addressToSave->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
            $addressToSave->setIsDefaultBilling(
                (bool)$this->getRequest()->getParam('default_billing', false)
            );
            $addressToSave->setIsDefaultShipping(
                (bool)$this->getRequest()->getParam('default_shipping', false)
            );
            if ($addressId) {
                $addressToSave->setId($addressId);
                $message = __('Customer address has been updated.');
            } else {
                $addressToSave->setId(null);
                $message = __('New customer address has been added.');
            }
            $savedAddress = $this->addressRepository->save($addressToSave);
            $addressId = $savedAddress->getId();
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $error = true;
            $message = __('There is no customer with such id.');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $error = true;
            $message = __($e->getMessage());
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $error = true;
            $message = __('We can\'t change customer address right now.');
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }

        $addressId = empty($addressId) ? null : $addressId;
        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultJson->setData(
            [
                'message' => $message,
                'error' => $error,
                'data' => [
                    'entity_id' => $addressId
                ]
            ]
        );

        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

It is just giving errors when trying to save "**A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later**."